# Should function-try-block of d'tor allow handling of throwing member-variable d'tor?

Tags: c++, noexcept, function-try-block

I have a class whose destructor is `noexcept(false)`. I know it only throws under certain circumstances, and I want to use it as a member variable of a class with a `noexcept` destructor. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block I read "Every exception thrown from any statement in the function body, or (for constructors) from any member or base constructor, or (for destructors) from any member or base destructor, transfers control to the handler-sequence the same way an exception thrown in a regular try block would." which makes me think this should be correct:

```
#include <exception>

class ConditionallyThrowingDtor {
public:
    bool willThrow = true;
    ConditionallyThrowingDtor() = default;
    ~ConditionallyThrowingDtor() noexcept(false) {
        if (willThrow) {
            throw std::exception();
        }
    }
};


class NonThrowingDtor {
public:
    ConditionallyThrowingDtor x;
    ~NonThrowingDtor() noexcept try {
        x.willThrow = false;
    } catch (...) { 
        // Ignore because we know it will never happen.
    }
};


int main() {
    // ConditionallyThrowingDtor y; // Throws on destruction as expected.
    NonThrowingDtor x;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ez17fx (MSVC)

My understanding of `noexcept` and the function-try-block on `~NonThrowingDtor()` is that `noexcept` guarantees it won't throw (and that it does this by essentially doing `try { ... } catch (...) { std::terminate(); }` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec. But the function-try-block with `catch (...)` and no additional throw should guarantee it never throws. Clang is OK with this, but as the godbolt link shows, MSVC says

```
<source>(23): warning C4297: 'NonThrowingDtor::~NonThrowingDtor': function assumed not to throw an exception but does
<source>(23): note: destructor or deallocator has a (possibly implicit) non-throwing exception specification
```

Comment: Why must the `catch` block necessarily rethrow? Are you saying that in as much as `noexcept` means `try { ... } catch (...) { std::terminate(); }`, that `noexcept try { ... } catch (...) {}` means `try { try { ... } catch (...) { std::terminate(); } } catch (...) {}`?

Comment: I was under the impression that it was not possible to leave a destructor's `catch` block without implicitly throwing, but apparently you can `return` to explicitly no rethrow.

Comment: @Jarod42 Destructors are similar to constructors in that they `throw;` when execution reaches the end of the `catch`. The difference is destructors allow you to `return;` to escape that behavior while constructors do not. I thought they were identical but this is not the case.

Comment: So warning is legit... Strange that using `return;` don't silent the warning though.

Comment: @Ben _"Why must the catch block necessarily rethrow? "_ — Because the standard says so: http://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#14.sentence-1.

Comment: Thank you. That is the right answer, it seems. So, then would a `return;` as suggested above from inside the handler give the behavior I was expecting? If we `return;` inside the function-try-block's handler then control does not reach the end of the handler of the function-try-block of a destructor, correct?

Comment: @Ben What problem are you trying to solve? It seems to me that there is no one. You just get a warning. I guess that warning are false-positive sometimes. At runtime, there is no exception thrown, therefore everything should work fine. BTW, note that GCC emits a warning as well even when no exception is thrown at runtime: https://godbolt.org/z/175vfq.

Comment: I'm trying to have my d'tor be legitimately not throw (or `std::terminate`) when it has a member `tbb::task_group`, which has a throwing d'tor similar to the example I described, where I cain call `m_group.wait()` and know it won't actually throw. I opted for manual management of the lifetime: https://godbolt.org/z/MsovKc but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Maybe I finally understand. You need to treat the object of `tbb::task_group` as if it would be nothrow-destructible since you 100% know that, in your case, it won't throw, right? And, of course, you cannot change its definition provided by the TBB library. That's an interesting question, but I don't see any other solution that wrapping `tbb::task_group` by some other class. What about wrapping by `std::unique_ptr`? https://godbolt.org/z/fTrTr1

Comment: By “legitimately” I mean no throwing, no `terminate`, no `exit`, just guaranteed clean return. I think my workaround works well since it saves allocation/deallocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~NonThrowingDtor() noexcept try {
        x.willThrow = false;
    } catch (...) { 
        // Ignore because we know it will never happen.
    }
```

is "wrong" as equivalent to

```
~NonThrowingDtor() noexcept try {
        x.willThrow = false;
    } catch (...) {
        throw;
    }
```

so simply

```
~NonThrowingDtor() noexcept
{
    x.willThrow = false;
}
```

To not propagate exception, you have to use explicitly `return`:

```
~NonThrowingDtor() noexcept try {
        x.willThrow = false;
    } catch (...) { 
        return; // Required to not propagate exception.
    }
```

Unfortunately, msvc still warns with this form which doesn't throw.
(On the other side, clang/gcc don't warn for **implicit** (but do for explicit) `throw` in that case).